# how to re-arrange quick settings list in lock screen?

Tags: settings, screen

I am able to re-arrange the quick settings list that is showing after unlocking the phone, however, the list that appears when you pull down while screen is locked cannot be changed. To make it clear, I am able to add the "hotspot" tile in the unlocked screen list but cannot find it when I open this list before unlocking the screen. This tile was available in my old HTC M9 device but it's not there anymore in my new Xperia XZ with Android 6.0.1
Can I do this without rooting?